# How Do I Gain System Permissions/Privileges On Windows 10 (Without Downloading Any Software)

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, administrator, uac

I'm doing deep modifications and experiments on a fresh install of Windows, but I cannot continue because I do not have SYSTEM permissions. I know SYSTEM privileges are incredibly powerful and dangerous. I am completely okay with destroying this install of Windows.

To clarify, I already have Admin permissions. I am concerned about system privileges, which allow you to stop protected services like the Antimalware Service Executable (aka Windows Defender / MsMpEng.exe). I don't specifically care about Windows Defender. I know that it's possible to stop this service in other ways.

I also know that it's possible to gain system permissions by downloading PsTools from Microsoft, but I'm looking for a way that does not require any downloads. All other options are on the table.

Comment: Pretty sure there's no such functionality available in Windows, there would be no need for PsExec otherwise.

Comment: You don't need to. Admins have the same power. You take ownership.

Comment: Have a look at the source of nsudo. https://github.com/M2Team/NSudo
You must decide if you trust this method but it is all standard APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a *scheduled task* through `taskschd.msc` – it will run the specified program or batch script with system privileges if that's what you specify.

(You could also create a custom service using `sc`; plain old .bat scripts won't be able to understand the specific requests that the Service Manager expects to use, but they'll still have a chance to do their job before the service startup "fails".)

Note that some actions are not allowed even to SYSTEM. For example, processes running with the "Protected process (Light)" security level cannot be normally controlled by SYSTEM in general (except through security vulnerabilities) – this includes most anti-malware processes, LSASS, and so on.